# React.memo JSX.Element types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If you have these simple components:

```js
const Simple = (_props) => {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
}

const SimpleMemo = React.memo(Simple);
const SimpleMemo2 = React.memo((_props): JSX.Element => {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
});
```

Then `SimpleMemo` and `SimpleMemo2` are inferred to be of different types. `SimpleMemo` is `React.MemoExoticComponent<(_props: any) => JSX.Element>` and `SimpleMemo2` is `React.NamedExoticComponent<object>`.

Furthermore, you can't set some properties for `SimpleMemo2` even though the code is the same:

```js
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Simple style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}/>
                <SimpleMemo style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}/>
                <SimpleMemo2 style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

This gives an error for `<SimpleMemo2 style=`:

```
Type '{ style: { backgroundColor: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'.
```

However it works fine for `SimpleMemo`. What is going on here? What's the difference between `MemoExoticComponent` and `NamedExoticComponent` and how can I make `SimpleMemo2` work without having to assign the function to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your props are not typed. So `SimpleMemo` "works" but it really just accepts any prop. For example this works fine, but really shouldn't:

```
<SimpleMemo thisDoesNotExist="butNoError" />
```

`SimpleMemo2` on the other hand works as expected - it's giving you an error because you're trying to pass a prop which the component is not expecting. To fix it, add all the props to the type:

```
type Props = {
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
};

const SimpleMemo2 = React.memo(({ style }: Props): JSX.Element => {
    return <div style={style}>Hello</div>;
});
```

Now you can use it without issues.